# What's the Prototype 1.6.0+ equivalent of 'document.getElementsByClassName'?

Tags: javascript, selector, prototypejs

Specifically I need the equivalent selector for this, which worked in Prototype 1.5.0:

```
//for each element with class of 'myClassName' and an ancestor with id='myElementID'...
document.getElementsByClassName('myClassName', $('myElementID')).each( ... );
```

I tried this:

```
$$('myElementID input.myClassName').each( ... ); //Because I will be selecting input elements with this class
```

and this:

```
$$('myElementID .myClassName').each( ... ); //Trying to get all child elements with this class name
```

I get an empty list every time. The child elements I want are not necessarily direct children, so I know the `>` character will not work.

I don't use Prototype and can't find help on this exact issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: this question really brings back memories.  Prototype was the first JS library I learned / used :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [$$](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/utility#method-%24%24) function will take any CSS Selector, so use a # to get `myElementID` by id.  The rest of the selector to get all the inputs with class `myClassName` inside of `myElementID` was correct.

```
$$('#myElementID input.myClassName').each( ... );
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the documentation it looks like the following should work ok :

```
$$('#myElementID .myClassName').each( ... );
```

http://www.prototypejs.org/api/utility/dollar-dollar